# Complete Screen Flicker when entering data in android listview Adapter

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I have a `ListView` inside `RelativeLayout` in a `Fragment`. I am getting data from server and in API call callback I am adding element to my CustomAdapter in follwoing way

```
   @Override
public void onResponse(List<Post> response) {
        mAdapter.clearAdapter();

        if (response.size() > 0) {
            for (Post post : response) {
                mAdapter.add(post);
            }

            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
}
```

problem is that this `mAdapter.add(post)` call is causing screen to flicker mometarily. I have also tried using `addAll()` instead of `add()` but no luck. I have been using `ListView` with custom adapters for a while and this is first time I am facing such issue. I am not sure where might be the issue. Also I am using same custom adapter at other places in app with out any such issue. This custom adapter derives from `ArrayAdapter`.

**Update**

I tried using a simple `ArrayAdapter<String>` with dummy data and issue is not getting reproduced.

**Update 2**

I removed everything from my custom adapter `getView()` method and reduced it to following. Still screen flickers

```
   @Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
    }
    return convertView;
}
```

**Update 3**

I have a `VideoView` in list-item xml layout which is causing this issue. If I comment that out flickering is gone.

Comment: show the method `getView` of your adapter

Comment: @Budius its too big and complicated to add here, I tried using a simple `ArrayAdapter<String>` and issue is not getting reproduced.

Comment: so you know that somewhere in this big and complicated method, you're doing something wrong or too time consuming.

Comment: @Budius I removed everything from my `getView()` method still I am getting that flickering. I have updated my question with reduced code.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal please could you provide your list item layout xml

Comment: @KevinCrain it was a dynamically inflated `VideoView` which was culprit.